# Wrap Text Around a Variable Amount of Images in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, image, text, swiftui

Wondering if anyone has any ideas about having a `Text` component wrap a variable amount of `Image` components at the beginning of a line . What I'm looking to accomplish is something like this:

[image]

where all rows of text after the first should wrap inline underneath that image, and there could be multiple images at the beginning of the line (let's say a max of 3). This is the code I currently have:

```swift
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
      BadgeImage(from: debugUrl)
      Text("\(Text(message.user).foregroundColor(message.color)): \(message.text)")
    }
    Spacer()
  }
  .padding(.horizontal, 10)
}
```

where `BadgeImage` is just a wrapper for `SwiftUI`'s `AsyncImage` that simply handles the `URL` object creation (ignore the `VStack` and `Spacer` just there for the picture).

I know we can interpolate an `Image` into `Text` with SwiftUI, but this doesn't help since the number of images is variable and has to be fetched from a URL, so I have to use `AsyncImage`. Manually implementing the async logic leaves me having to then do something like `Text("\(someStateVar) some text...")`, but seems like Swift only allows image interpolation at build time and using a state var leaves me with the string description of an image instead of the actual `Image` component within the text.

The core question is: is there a way to implement `Text` wrapping with a variable amount of `some View` components at the beginning of a line, or does this have to be manually implemented with something like `CoreText`?

Comment: You don’t have to wrap the text. You can insert images as text into text… https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-insert-images-into-text

Comment: Right, the issue is SwiftUI doesn't allow interpolation for `AsyncImage`. And manually loading the images, then throwing them into a state var ends up displaying a string description of an `Image` object rather than displaying them inline (say something like `Text("\(someStateVar) some text...")` where I set `someStateVar` to `"\(Text(asyncLoadedImage))"`

Comment: Don’t use string interpolation `“\()”` use `Text(Image(uiImage: theStateVar)) + Text(“… some text”)` I forget the exact syntax for loading Image from UIImage but it’s something like that. Look at the link I posted. It doesn’t use string interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Fogmeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421018/fogmeister) for the tip! Went with just doing `Text(someImageVar) + Text("The text...)` and this works great. I've now just got something like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
  HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    content
  }
  .padding(.horizontal, 10)
  .padding(.vertical, 1)
  .onAppear(perform: onAppear)
}
```

And the `onAppear` logic just runs an async `Task` and ends up doing `content = content + Text(newlyLoadedImage)`