# In SwiftUI, how can I wrap a text view around an image view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Put simply, I want to achieve what is shown in this image.

There is an image and a text placed side by side. The text starts on the same height as the image, then when it has enough space, it continues from the leading edge.

Visual description:

[image]

The code I have does not wrap the text once there is enough space. This is what it displays:

Rendered view:

[image]

I am using the latest version of SwiftUI.

```
VStack {
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619679505795-a4d0e6be5e02?q=80&w=1964&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D")) { phase in
            if let image = phase.image {
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            } else if phase.error != nil {
                Text("There was an error loading the image.")
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, alignment: .leading) { size, axis in
            size * 0.25
        }
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas bibendum magna magna, eget dignissim leo lobortis eget.Maecenas bibendum magna magna, eget dignissim leo lobortis eget. Sed metus quam, condimentum in quam vel, rhoncus tempor purus. Proin tortor augue, commodo eu turpis in, rhoncus varius lorem. Morbi ut sapien eget diam viverra mattis quis et augue.")
            .padding(.leading)
    }
}
.padding(.horizontal, 12)
.padding(.vertical, 20)
.border(Color.black)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494344/wrap-text-around-some-view-in-swiftui ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70545812/wrap-text-around-a-variable-amount-of-images-in-swiftui ?

Comment: The answer's there either no longer work, or are not applicable here because I am using an AsyncImage

Comment: @StillAyo - it doesn't look like SwiftUI can do that... So, one approach is to use a `UITextView` as `UIViewRepresentable`, and implement `exclusionPaths` -- as shown in Larme's first link. Of course, you'd need to edit that code to accommodate your use of AsyncImage

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve text wrapping in your code is by using `GeometryReader`. This SwiftUI view allows you to specify a frame for your text and then wraps the text inside that frame. Using `GeometryReader`, you can ensure that your text wraps correctly, irrespective of the device or screen size.

This would be your modified code:

```swift
VStack {
    HStack(alignment: .top) {
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619679505795-a4d0e6be5e02?q=80&w=1964&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D")) { phase in
            if let image = phase.image {
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            } else if phase.error != nil {
                Text("There was an error loading the image.")
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100) // Adjust as per your image size
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas bibendum magna magna, eget dignissim leo lobortis eget.Maecenas bibendum magna magna, eget dignissim leo lobortis eget. Sed metus quam, condimentum in quam vel, rhoncus tempor purus. Proin tortor augue, commodo eu turpis in, rhoncus varius lorem. Morbi ut sapien eget diam viverra mattis quis et augue.")
                .padding(.leading)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
}
.padding(12)
.border(Color.black)
```

[image: Code]

I hope that I was able to help you. If there's anything I misunderstood, just let me know. I'll be happy to fix any issues and explain the solution to you in detail.

Comment: The question is how to get the text flow also *beneath* the image.

Comment: Yeah, i'd like to to also go underneath the image if the text is long enough